# Joomla 3.x: Installation using MSSQL as Database

Tags: database

I tried to do some research, but couldn't find one. Maybe someone can help!
I want to install Joomla 3.x using MS SQL server as DB. Right now, I only can choose Mysql.

PHP version - 5.6 + WAMP!

What I've done:

1. Downloaded SQLSRV20.EXE and installed it in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext
2. WAMP -> PHP -> php.ini (Added this line along the other php_sqlsrv_..x..)

   extension=php_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll

Followed this tutorial: https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_sqlserver

Result: I still don't see option to install Joomla using MSSQL as DB. What am I doing wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the advice is old, outdated, incomplete...

This seems more relevant to your needs:
http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php

The two points that leap out of text as not matching your description are that you do not actually mention whether you are actually running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client and that the advice suggests version 3.0 of the extension. [Microsoft actually has 3.2 of it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) , which is probably what you want. The version 2.0 is still recommended for php compiled with vc6 which is what the advice you followed was probably about. And no, if you just installed newest version of WAMP it is unlikely to have php compiled with vc6. Also you must have either 64 bit or 32 bit versions not a mix of the two, which might trip you if just following advice.

Note that the link I added above is **also** outdated. If you look at the [Microsoft requirements page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver) you'll see that Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client is only for version 3.0 and 3.2 actually requires Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server...

Good luck! Hope that the more up-to-date links help!

Answer (score 1):

You should need to install "MS SQL server drivers for PHP" version 3.2 or 4.0.
Unpack on php/ext folder and once done you have to enable the extension in php.ini such as

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_x64.dll
```

Notes:

1. change dll filename based on your extracted files.
2. don't mix x86 and x64 dlls
3. you can use /path/to/file.dll instead of filename dll

Finally reloading http://localhost/joomla website you will get Sqlsrv or MS SQL server option in your combobox.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour], consider giving your account a non-generic name, and perhaps tell us about you and your Joomla experiences by editing your profile.

Answer (score 0):

it's true! 
before the installation go to joomla_root\installation\sql
there is only 3 folders (mysql - postgersql - sqlazure) and MSSQL is not included